# Pandas plot axvspan

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I have a dataframe like this

```
from datetime import date
import random

start_date = date.today().replace(day=1, month=1).toordinal()
end_date = date.today().toordinal()

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'dates':[ date.fromordinal(random.randint(start_date, end_date)) for i in xrange(10) ]
                        ,'n':np.random.randint(0,100,10)})
df.index=df['dates']; del df['dates']
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Which generates

```
             n
dates         
2016-01-24   0
2016-02-26  98
2016-03-04  68
2016-03-26  45
2016-05-03  89
2016-05-09  83
2016-05-11  58
2016-07-29  53
2016-09-18  79
2016-10-20  57
```

I would like to plot it and have a axvspan for February and March. Since my dates are random how can I select those 2 months and use axvspan

my plotting code is simple

```
ax=df.plot()
```

Comment: Does axvspan(pd.datetime(2016, 2, 1), pd.datetime(2016,4,1)) give you what you want?

Comment: That works. For some reason when I do ax.axvspan(pd.datetime(2016, 2, 1), pd.datetime(2016,4,1)) inside a loop I don't see anything. Otherwise it works

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example. It has to be improved if the dates span over several years. You can also check the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480232/pandas-plots-separate-color-for-weekends-pretty-printing-times-on-x-axis) since the principle is exactly the same.

```
ax = df.plot()
# Getting the boundaries for dates in feb and march
period = df[(df.index.month > 1) & (df.index.month < 3)].index
# Highlighting
ax.axvspan(min(period) - MonthBegin(), max(period) + MonthEnd(),
           facecolor='g', edgecolor='none', alpha=.2)
```

[image]