# Plotly: How to highlight weekends without looping through the dataset?

Tags: python, time-series, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to plot three different timeseries dataframes (each around 60000 records) using plotly, while highlighting weekends (and workhours) with a different background color.

Is there a way to do it without looping through the whole dataset as mentioned in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65174049/1831518). While this method might work, the performance can be poor on large datasets

Comment: Check `fig.layout['shapes']` in the answer given as an example question to understand the structure. You can do this by creating as many of these dictionary settings as you need and setting them as follows. `fig.layout['shapes']=[...]` However, I don't know how much it will improve the speed because I think it will be created by looping or using comprehension notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would consider using `make_subplots` and attach a `go.Scatter` trace to the secondary y-axis to act as a background color instead of shapes to indicate weekends.

#### Essential code elements:

```
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['date'], y=df.weekend,
                         fill = 'tonexty', fillcolor = 'rgba(99, 110, 250, 0.2)',
                         line_shape = 'hv', line_color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                         showlegend = False
                        ),
              row = 1, col = 1, secondary_y=True)
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import datetime
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

# data sample
cols = ['signal']
nperiods = 50
np.random.seed(2)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-1, 2, size=(nperiods, len(cols))),
                  columns=cols)
datelist = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),periods=nperiods).tolist()
df['date'] = datelist 
df = df.set_index(['date'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.iloc[0] = 0
df = df.cumsum().reset_index()
df['signal'] = df['signal'] + 100
df['weekend'] = np.where((df.date.dt.weekday == 5) | (df.date.dt.weekday == 6), 1, 0 )

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['date'], y=df.weekend,
                         fill = 'tonexty', fillcolor = 'rgba(99, 110, 250, 0.2)',
                         line_shape = 'hv', line_color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                         showlegend = False
                        ),
              row = 1, col = 1, secondary_y=True)

fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=False)#, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='rgba(0,0,255,0.1)')
fig.update_layout(yaxis2_range=[-0,0.1], yaxis2_showgrid=False,  yaxis2_tickfont_color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['date'], y = df.signal, line_color = 'blue'), secondary_y = False)

fig.show()
```

#### Speed tests:

For `nperiods = 2000` in the code snippet below on my system, `%%timeit` returns:

```
162 ms ± 1.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The approach in my original suggestion using `fig.add_shape()` is considerably slower:

```
49.2 s ± 2.18 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a filled area chart to highlight all weekends at once without using a loop and without creating multiple shapes, see the code below for an example.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# generate a time series
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', periods=18, freq='D'),
    'value': 100 * np.cumsum(np.random.normal(loc=0.01, scale=0.005, size=18))
})

# define the y-axis limits
ymin, ymax = df['value'].min() - 5, df['value'].max() + 5

# create an auxiliary time series for highlighting the weekends, equal
# to "ymax" on Saturday and Sunday, and to "ymin" on the other days
df['weekend'] = np.where(df['date'].dt.day_name().isin(['Saturday', 'Sunday']), ymax, ymin)

# define the figure layout
layout = dict(
    plot_bgcolor='white',
    paper_bgcolor='white',
    margin=dict(t=5, b=5, l=5, r=5, pad=0),
    yaxis=dict(
        range=[ymin, ymax],  # fix the y-axis limits
        tickfont=dict(size=6),
        linecolor='#000000',
        color='#000000',
        showgrid=False,
        mirror=True
    ),
    xaxis=dict(
        type='date',
        tickformat='%d-%b-%Y (%a)',
        tickfont=dict(size=6),
        nticks=20,
        linecolor='#000000',
        color='#000000',
        ticks='outside',
        mirror=True
    ),
)

# add the figure traces
data = []

# plot the weekends as a filled area chart
data.append(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df['date'],
        y=df['weekend'],
        fill='tonext',
        fillcolor='#d9d9d9',
        mode='lines',
        line=dict(width=0, shape='hvh'),
        showlegend=False,
        hoverinfo=None,
    )
)

# plot the time series as a line chart
data.append(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df['date'],
        y=df['value'],
        mode='lines+markers',
        marker=dict(size=4, color='#cc503e'),
        line=dict(width=1, color='#cc503e'),
        showlegend=False,
    )
)

# create the figure
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

# save the figure
fig.write_image('figure.png', scale=2, width=500, height=300)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two minor modifications to @vestland's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69177656/8331132) (see the code block below) fixed the following for me:

- Data points lie on the *edges* and not clearly *inside* the shaded vertical bars. It's fixed by using `hvh` for `line_shape`. See docs [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-line-shape).
- The shaded vertical bar for the last weekend is missing. It's fixed by using `tozeroy` for `fill`. See docs [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-fill).

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(...,
                         fill = 'tozeroy', # Changed from 'tonexty'.                         
                         line_shape = 'hvh', # Changed from 'hv'.
                         ...,
                        ),
```